# Dynamically adding ElementHost'd WPF UserControl to WinForms results in Black

Tags: wpf, winforms, elementhost

I have a WPF user control inside an `ElementHost` that is inside a WinForms control to wrap it. I'm dynamically adding it to a tab control tab.

But when I do this, my WPF control is black.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my own mistake. I forgot to add the WinForms tab control panel (a 3rd party one) to the right class.

Answer (score 1):

There are many alternative solutions on the web to this one. However, what fixed it for us was to avoid "Fill" docking the element host within it's parent control. If you are using docking, then give it a try!

Unfortunately this can be one of those evil problems solved by experimentation and it'll turn out to be a one line fix!

Comment: +1 for the suggestion, however it was my own <strike>stupidity</strike> mistake.